# Does a process always need to be terminated?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am using a Python process to run one of my functions like so:

```
Process1 = Process(target = someFunction)
Process1.start()
```

Now that function has no looping or anything, it just does its thing, then ends, does the Process die with it? or do I always need to drop a:

```
Process1.terminate()
```

Afterwards?

Comment: All the information you need is in the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [as per the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) it only sends a `SIGTERM` or `TerminateProcess()` to the process in question. If it has already exited then there is nothing to terminate.

However, it is always a good process to use exit codes in your subprocesses:

```
import sys
sys.exit(1)
```

And then check the [exit code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.exitcode) once you know the process has terminated:

```
if Process1.exitcode():
   errorHandle()
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much. I will accept this as answered in 4 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

The child process will exit by itself - the `Process1.terminate()` is unnecessary in that regard.  This is especially true if using any shared resources between the child and parent process.  From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#all-start-methods):

> Avoid terminating processes
>
> Using the Process.terminate method to stop a process is liable to cause any shared resources (such as locks, semaphores, pipes and queues) currently being used by the process to become broken or unavailable to other processes.
>
> Therefore it is probably best to only consider using Process.terminate on processes which never use any shared resources.

However, if you want the parent process to *wait* for the child process to finish (perhaps the child process is modifying something that the parent will access afterwards), then you'll want to use `Process1.join()` to block the parent process from continuing until the child process complete.  This is generally good practice when using child processes to avoid zombie processes or orphaned children.